# Understanding how "WhatsApp Web" front-end page was developed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to understand how the *WhatsApp Web* front-end page was created, especially the list of contacts on the left side (`<div id="pane-side">`). The name of the contacts uses the class `"emojitext ellipsify"` and I am trying to get the name of all contacts by the code:

```
var contatosTemp = document.getElementsByClassName('emojitext ellipsify');
var contatos = [];
for (var i = 0; i < contatosTemp.length; i = i + 2) { contatos.push(contatosTemp[i].innerText); }
contatos
```

If the scroll of the list of contacts is at top, the number of `contatos` are `19`. But if I scroll the list, the number of `contatos` is increased until the number of `29`. If I minimize the window, the number of `contatos` is decreased to `15`.

At resume, the number of the list of contacts caught by the JavaScript above changes when the user scrolls the list of contacts.

If you want to understand what I am doing, open your *WhatsApp Web*, go to browser *DevTools > Console* and run the JavaScript above.

You will see the size of the array `contatos`:
[image]

Then scroll the pane at left side of screen and execute the JavaScript again. It will show that the array size changed.

I would like to get all the contacts' names but JavaScript only gets part of it. How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of screen scraping, have you considered trying any of the available WhatsApp APIs?

Comment: Whatsapp provides some APIs? I thought not.

Comment: WhatsApp themselves apparently not - that's why there seem to be a variety of rogue ones around ([Yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup), etc.).

Comment: Do you know any Whatsapp API for C# ?

Comment: Quick search turns out there's a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WhatsAppAPI/)

Comment: Nuget package works? It says "The goal of this fork is to make it all work again and refacter the code".

Comment: You are aware that now everyone can see the phone numbers of two of your friends? You might want to check with them if they're okay with that..

Answer (score 1):

Use this script that will bring you all the contacts

```
function contactList(){
   var user = Store.Chat.models; 
   var destiny = [];

   user.forEach(function(obj){destiny.push(obj.__x_formattedTitle)});
   return destiny }
```